# interpret .cfm files with .net IIS 7.5

Tags: iis-7.5, asp.net

I'm trying to do some redirecting from some old coldfusion files that are still indexed on our system here to their new counterparts.

Because the cold fusion files don't actually exist any more, I want to use .net for the redirect.

I read this suggestion here: [In IIS, Is it possible to execute a .HTML page as aspx?](https://serverfault.com/questions/282971/in-iis-is-it-possible-to-execute-a-html-page-as-aspx) about how to interpret .html files with .net and tried the same approach for .cfm with no success.  My site is set up in integrated mode so the only change I made was to the web.config per the suggestion in that post.  When I hit the .cfm page, I get a 404 for some reason.  If I rename it to .aspx, it works just fine.

the site I'm working under is .net mvc 3 if that makes any difference.

Comment: This is a confusing question - do the CFM files exist? What are you renaming to/from CFM if not? As far as I can tell, you've got the right answer for what you seem to be trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Was ColdFusion previously installed on this server?  Is the 404 error coming from IIS or is it the gray ColdFusion error box?

Within IIS 7.5, go to the properties for the website and look at the Handler Mappings.  If there is still an entry in there for .cfm files, disable them.

If ColdFusion is still installed and running, you can recreate the .cfm files and put the following lines of code in place to redirect requests:

```
<cfheader statuscode="301" statustext="Moved">
<cfheader name="Location" value="new-url.aspx">
```